# Nested ordered list within <dd> element [HTML5]

Tags: html, list

I have an HTML5 nested list assignment where we have to produce this output:

https://gyazo.com/b9f77a413c0c0e55aaa294ed5b3c346a

In order for the ordered list under the first term to appear the way it does in his example, I decided to nest the list under the `<dd>` element. Any other way I try does not work.

However it produces this result when I try to code it:

https://gyazo.com/06ecff49a788d4f18bc451a5195571c3

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html/>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Question One</title>
        <h1>Exercise on HTML5 Lists</h1>
    </head>
    <body>
        <dl>
            <dt>term 1 (definition list)</dt>
            <dd>
                term 1 description
                <ol>
                    <li>ol list item 1</li>
                    <li>ol list item 2</li>
                    <ul>
                        <li>ul list item 1</li>
                        <li>ul list item 2</li>
                    </ul>
                </ol>   
            </dd>   
        </dl>
        <dl>
            <dt>term 2 (definition list)</dt>
            <dd>
                term 2 description
                <ul>
                    <li>ul list item 3</li>
                    <li>ul list item 4</li>
                        <ol>
                            <li>ol list item 3</li>
                            <li>ol list item 4</li>
                        </ol>
                    <li>ul list item 5</li>
                    <li>ul list item 6</li>
                </ul>
            </dd>
        </dl>
    </body> 
</html>
```

Sorry about the links to images instead of images themselves, i'm a noob and need 10 rep to post images. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you explain what aspects of this are an issue?  For example, if the problem is the space before each list, that can be solved with CSS, but it isn't clear if that is available to you.

Comment: The problem is the spacing. The teacher said there is no CSS needed to solve the problem though. Please note I'm loading this on OSX as opposed to the professor using windows (not sure if that makes a difference). Why are there gaps to begin with though?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't really describe what the issue is, but the only difference I can see between the two pictures is the spacing and font. I'm assuming the issue is spacing.

Add the following block to your HTML file.

```
<style>

ol, ul {
    margin-top: 0;
}

</style>
```

Does this solve your problem?

Comment: Isn't this using CSS, which OP (in a comment) says isn't necessary?

Comment: I didn't see his comment about that. It could be a browser issue. Can you think of anything else that would cause this discrepancy?

Comment: @taylorsabell I tried using Safari instead of chrome and it displays the same